# Coefficients of $(1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^7)^{10}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I've been asked to find the coefficient of $x^{25}$ in $(1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^7)^{10}$. While reasoning through the problem, I was thinking that this seems equivalent to solving the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
0\cdot x_1 + 2\cdot x_2 + 4\cdot x_3 + 7\cdot x_4 = 25 \\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 10 \\
x_i \geq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
While at first, this seemed helpful to me, I am not sure where to proceed from here. I have a feeling that either a clever use of generating functions or the multinomial theorem would be helpful, but I can't figure out how to go about it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can be solved with dynamic programming I suppose

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about what I just wrote in this comment, so this comment may not be helpful at all. But I wrote $(1)^a(x^2)^b(x^4)^c(x^7)^d=x^{25}$, where $0\le a,b,c,d \le 3$ are integers. In particular, for an easy choice I set $a=0$ and found $b=c=3$ and $d=1$. Then using the multinomial theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem), I found the coefficient to be $${10 \choose a,b,c,d} = {10 \choose 0,3,3,1} = \frac{10!}{0!3!3!1!}=100800.$$ Again, I'm not sure if this were correct; if what I just said isn't right, I could use the help as well.

Comment: There are also choices of $a=b=0$, $c=1$, $d=3$ and $a=0$, $b=2$, $c=5$, $d=0$, both of which also satisfy $(1)^a(x^2)^b(x^4)^c(x^7)^d=x^{25}$, but these choices of $a,b,c,d$ lead to multinomial coefficients that are different from the one in my last comment. Never mind what I just said, then... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's easiest if you break it up into cases.  Since 25 is odd and of the exponents only $x^7$ is an odd power, it follows that the only terms contributing to $x^{25}$ are those that use one or three factors of $x^7$.

In essence, the desired coefficient is the same as taking the sum of the coefficients of $x^{18}y$ and $x^{4}y^3$ in the expansion of $(1+x^2+x^4+y)^{10}$.

This reduces the computation to the following pieces:

- You need to count the number of ways you can select one or three of the ten factors to correspond to the chosen factors of $x^7$, depending on the case.
- You need to determine the coefficient of $x^{18}$ in $(1+x^2+x^4)^{9}$.
- You need to determine the coefficient of $x^{4}$ in $(1+x^2+x^4)^7$.

The first of these should be routine, the second is trivial, and since the power of $x$ is low enough, the coefficient for the third is the same as if you were expanding $(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\ldots)^7$ instead.

Comment: Shouldn't the $2$ places where you used $(1+x+x^2)$ be $(1+x^2+x^4)$ instead?

Comment: @JohnOmielan you're right, fixed, that makes things easier since no inclusion-exclusion is required

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is rather unusual but might be interesting. We consider the polynomial
\begin{align*}
p(x)=\left(1+x^2+x^4+x^7\right)^{10}=\sum_{k=0}^{70}a_kx^k
\end{align*}
and are looking for $a_{25}$. We do so by using the technique of *[series multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection)*. Usually this technique is used to *filter* out elements in a periodical manner and obtain for instance a polynomial containing every third element in $p(x)$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor 70/3\rfloor} a_{3k}x^{3k}
\end{align*}

> To get $a_{25}$ we use this technique to filter out each element but the first and apply a shift by $25$. In order to do so, we take the smallest prime $p$ greater than $70$, i.e. $p=71$ and consider a *[primitive $p$-th root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#General_definition)* of unity:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \omega=e^{2\pi i /71}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{a_{25}}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{71}\sum_{k=0}^{70}e^{-50k\pi i/71}\left(1+e^{4k\pi i/71}+e^{8k\pi i/71}+e^{14k\pi i/71}\right)^{10}}\\
> &\color{blue}{\,\,=34\,750}
> \end{align*}
>   where the value was found with some help of Wolfram Alpha.